# How to modify the existing function in oracle

Tags: oracle, function, sqlplus

I have created a pl/sql function like this

```
CREATE  Function conc(name IN varchar2)
RETURN varchar2 DETERMINISTIC
IS
fn varchar2(30);

BEGIN
    SELECT concat(fname,lname) into fn
    FROM tab1 where fname=name;

    return fn;
End;
/
```

It got created successfully with out any compilation errors.
Now I have tried to changed the above existing function using replace

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function conc(name IN varchar2)
RETURN varchar2 DETERMINISTIC
IS
fn varchar2(30);

BEGIN
    SELECT concat(lname,fname) into fn
    FROM tab1 where fname=name;

    return fn;
End;
/
```

Here the function is created with compilation errors.

Can some one suggest why this happens and what is the best way to change the existing pl/sql function definition.

Comment: Use `show errors` to see the actual problems found, or query the `user_errors` view.

Comment: you can also get interactive feedback showing your compilation errors if you use our IDE, Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: And not directly relevant, but: ["Do not specify DETERMINISTIC for a function whose result depends on the state of session variables or schema objects"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/function.htm#CJAFICJJ).

Comment: May be you can post the compilation error?

Answer (score 0):

There is no syntax error with your second code where you are using 'Create Or Replace'. That is the right way to edit an existing function. I was able to create it in my development environment. See below:

```html
SQL> create table tab1 (
  2  lname varchar2(15),
  3  fname varchar2(15),
  4  create_dt date
  5  )
  6  /

Table created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE Function conc(name IN varchar2)
  2  RETURN varchar2 DETERMINISTIC
  3  IS
  4  fn varchar2(30);
  5  
  6  BEGIN
  7      SELECT concat(lname,fname) into fn
  8      FROM tab1 where fname=name;
  9  
 10      return fn;
 11  End;
 12  /

Function created.
```

There are few ways to see the errors. First, and most common one, is 'Show errors' as mentioned by Alex Pool above. Alternatively, you can also query the table user_errors (or all_errors appropriately) for all the details you may need to debug. See below where I intentionally dropped the table to get errors:

```html
SQL> drop table tab1;

Table dropped.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE Function conc(name IN varchar2)
  2  RETURN varchar2 DETERMINISTIC
  3  IS
  4  fn varchar2(30);
  5  
  6  BEGIN
  7      SELECT concat(lname,fname) into fn
  8      FROM tab1 where fname=name;
  9  
 10      return fn;
 11  End;
 12  /

Warning: Function created with compilation errors.

SQL> select line, text  from user_errors where NAME='CONC';

      LINE
----------
TEXT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         8
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

         7
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

Interestingly, it appears that this tables gets cleared every time you run a statement. See below:

```html
SQL> drop Function conc;

Function dropped.

SQL> select line, text  from user_errors where NAME='CONC';

no rows selected

SQL>
```

Btw, when you tried to create your function code, did you receive any feedback from the system. You should expect either 'Function created.' or 'Warning: Function created with compilation errors.'?  If not, you may want to check your environmental setting. Hope this helps!